# How do I get the console output of another program, preferably in python?

Tags: python, console, output

I am working on a Raspberry PI, and I made a Python application that takes care of communication with a hardware device. This program starts on boot-up.

The person I am making it for wants to be able to see the output of the console of the program while it is running. How can I get the output of a different program? Screen was suggested, but its ability to remotely kill the program with it is not desirable.

Comment: The usual way is to redirect the output of the program using the OS facilities. You can use `tee` if you need to both see it on the console and capture it at the same time.

Comment: log to a file, `tail -f logfile`?